# YesNo Message box OnTop

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use a MessageBox.Show command with the YesNo options. What I am needing is for it to be always on top.

Current code:

```
 Try
                Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Dsign has been reset. Would you like to make a ticket?", "Dsign", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

                If result = DialogResult.No Then
                    BGDsign.ReportProgress(100, "Dsign Reset")
                    Exit Sub
                ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
                End If

            Catch
            End Try
```

I know how to use the `Form.ShowDialog()`but unsure how to do it for a yesno message box.

Comment: Same way, use an overload that lets you set the *owner* argument.  [This one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba2a6d06%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Or fix the threading bug in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `MessageBox.Show`, try this

```
Dim result As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Dsign has been reset. Would you like to make a ticket?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.SystemModal, "Dsign")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just tried it, did the same thing. Just a normal window, but not ontop.

Comment: That did it! You rock sir!